# Trying to make function that simplifies a list of integers by grouping repeats

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I want to make a function in python that takes a list with more than 1 element of numerically ordered integers as an input and returns a list of the same integers as an output but any repeats are grouped together in a list of their own, with this list being an element within the returned list by the function. For example:

`[3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6]` will return as `[[3,3],[4,4,4],5,[6,6]]`

I've tried to embed multiple if statements for each condition but that gets way too messy, way too quickly.

```
def simplify(mylist):
    if len(mylist) > 1:
        newlist = []
        for i in range(0, len(mylist) - 1):
            if (mylist[i] == mylist[i + 1]):
                count = 2
                group = [mylist[i], mylist[i]]
                while (i + count) <= (len(mylist) - 1):
                    if mylist[i] == mylist[i + count]:
                        group.append(mylist[i])
                        count += 1
                    else:
                        newlist.append(group)
                        break
            else:
                newlist.append(mylist[i])
        print(newlist)
        return (newlist)
```

So I expected it to do what I described the function should do but then it resulted in a list with elements that repeated being repeated in lists decreasing by one element until it finished iterating and did not append the last value. Example:

input `[3,4,4,4,4,5]`

returned `[3,[4,4,4,4],[4,4,4],[4,4],4]`

Comment: do you need to write a function without using python inbuilt method? you can do this with counter easily

Comment: if you want `[[3, 3], [4, 4, 4], 5, [6, 6]]` as an output, please check my answer.

Comment: What happens if the input is `[3, 3, 4, 3, 3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Counter

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = [3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6]
C = Counter(mylist)
output=[ [key,]*val if val >1 else key for key,val in C.items()]
```

Comment: `[key] * val if val > 1 else key` would do what OP wants

Answer (score 2):

Given the inpt is **already sorted** you should just use `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

def simplify(mylist):
     return [list(group) for key, group in groupby(mylist)]
```

It will give you:

```
In [14]: simplify([3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6])
Out[14]: [[3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [5], [6, 6]]
```

Comment: How would you change `[5]` to `5`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I wouln't change it, it is somewhat better when you have list containing lists and not list containing lists or integers. For whatever reason you need it that way it will only complicate the code. This function does one thing and does it well. Groups the numbers, it should be responsibility of different piece of code to unpack it

Comment: I happen to completely agree with you. For some reason OP wants it the other way.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you don't want item to be a list if it only occurred once,

```
from collections import Counter
x = [3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6]
output_list = []
for key, value in Counter(x).items():
    if value != 1:
        output_list.append([key]*value)
    else:
        output_list.append(key)

print(output_list)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 3], [4, 4, 4], 5, [6, 6]]
```

Comment: What happens if the input is `[3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,4]`? This would group into `[[3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], 5, [6, 6]]`, which is no longer just grouping repeats adjacent to each other. The OP would need to clarify if he wants all grouped repeats together or just adjacent repeats.